# Trying to use the ternary operator to display the value of a variable if the variable is greater than a given number

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I am going through the JavaScript curriculum of FreeCodeCamp and I am stuck trying to get a return value for the 'hit' variable by using a ternary operator.

**What FCC wants me to do to pass the challenge**:

> In getMonsterAttackValue, change return hit to a ternary operator that returns hit if hit is greater than 0, or returns 0 if it is not.

```
function getMonsterAttackValue(level) {
  const hit = (level * 5) - (Math.floor(Math.random() * xp));
  console.log(hit); 
  return hit > 0 ? 'hit' : '0'
  
}
```

Comment: I think you've slightly misunderstood the requirements of the problem: it doesn't want the string `'hit'`, it wants _the value of the `hit` variable_. Or in other words, "if `hit` is less than 0, act as though it was 0; otherwise, just return it as before".

Comment: I have attempted to change it to call the hit variable instead of the string, if that is what you mean but it's still a no go.

Comment: Show how you changed it to return the hit variable and we can help with that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how returning the **value of `hit` variable** "*still a no go*".

Comment: Thank you. I was using the strings but changed to **return hit > 0 ? hit : 0;**  instead and it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply take the larger value with [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

```
return Math.max(hit, 0);
```